# Can't get my input value bindings working properly in Svelte 3

Tags: javascript, forms, svelte, svelte-3

I am trying to make a form using Svelte 3. I have some inputs in my form. And I am using #each block to make multiple inputs. But the problem is that the value bindings for the inputs are getting mixed up and behaving weird. Here's my REPL

https://svelte.dev/repl/bdc37a81cbe04654a44b138dd973b16b?version=3.31.0

Try writing anything in input option 1, the words from input option 1 jump to input option 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because of your placeholder:

```
placeholder="Option {i += 1}"
```

You'r changing `i`'s value, try:

```
placeholder="Option {i + 1}"
```

Comment: I don't know why I was trying to increment i by one. I don't have to increment the value of i because #each block increments it already. So I don't even have to write placeholder="Option {i + 1}". I just had to write placeholder="Option {i}". Thanks for bringing it in my attention. On second though, writing i + 1 gives me the accurate option number. So your solution is the best way to get out of this problem.